# Protein Pre Workout or Post Workout which one is better for me?

Tags: protein-shakes

I am 27 years old my weight is 102 KG currently on Keto diet. I work at night and my shift ends at 3:00 AM. My last meal end at 12:00 AM, I go to gym at 11:00 AM.

My questions is should I drink protein before workout or after workout?

Answer (score 1):

Protein shakes will be most effective when your muscles are in a state of disrepair. As such, you should drink it *after* the workout.

Before the workout, consider eating/drinking something that gives you more energy in the gym, such as fruit and/or a handful of nuts. Optionally, there are pre-workout supplements out there, but I'd rather advise that you look to food instead of supplements whenever possible.